# Doctrine: How to select a store attached to a user entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a User entity with attached stores in a many to many relationship database.
I'm loading the stores in my controller with:

```
$userrepository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Thuiswinkelen\Entity\User');
$user      = $userrepository->findOneBy(array('id' => $this->getUserId()));
$stores = $user->getStores();
```

This is working fine.

Now i want the logged in user to select a store attached to him and show him all the products in that store.

I thought something like this:

```
$user->getStore($storeid)->getProducts();
```

This is not working, because i don't have the entity set like this. 
I also think this is a bad practice(?)

A second option is this

```
$storerepository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Thuiswinkelen\Entity\Store');
$store      = $storerepository->findOneBy(array('id' => $storeid));
```

But in this case, everyone can view the products from a store that is not attached to them.

How to do this?

My entities look like this:

Entity/User.php

```
        <?php

        namespace Application\Entity;

        use BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ProviderInterface;
        use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
        use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
        use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
        use ZfcUser\Entity\UserInterface;

        /**
         * An example of how to implement a role aware user entity.
         *
         * @ORM\Entity
         * @ORM\Table(name="users")
         * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Repositories\UserRepository")
         *
         * @author Tom Oram <tom@scl.co.uk>
         */
        class User implements UserInterface, ProviderInterface
        {
            /**
             * @var int
             * @ORM\Id
             * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
             * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
             */
            protected $id;

            /**
             * @var string
             * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $username;

            /**
             * @var string
             * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true,  length=255)
             */
            protected $email;

            /**
             * @var string
             * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $displayName;

            /**
             * @var string
             * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
             */
            protected $password;

            /**
             * @var int
             */
            protected $state;

            /**
             * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
             * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Role")
             * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role_linker",
             *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
             *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
             * )
             */
            protected $roles;

            /**
                 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
                 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Store")
                 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_store_linker",
                 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
                 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="store_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
                 * )
             */
            protected $stores;


            /**
             * Initialies the roles variable.
             */
            public function __construct()
            {
                $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
                $this->stores = new ArrayCollection();
            }

            /**
             * Get id.
             *
             * @return int
             */
            public function getId()
            {
                return $this->id;
            }

            /**
             * Set id.
             *
             * @param int $id
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function setId($id)
            {
                $this->id = (int) $id;
            }

            /**
             * Get username.
             *
             * @return string
             */
            public function getUsername()
            {
                return $this->username;
            }

            /**
             * Set username.
             *
             * @param string $username
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function setUsername($username)
            {
                $this->username = $username;
            }

            /**
             * Get email.
             *
             * @return string
             */
            public function getEmail()
            {
                return $this->email;
            }

            /**
             * Set email.
             *
             * @param string $email
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function setEmail($email)
            {
                $this->email = $email;
            }

            /**
             * Get displayName.
             *
             * @return string
             */
            public function getDisplayName()
            {
                return $this->displayName;
            }

            /**
             * Set displayName.
             *
             * @param string $displayName
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function setDisplayName($displayName)
            {
                $this->displayName = $displayName;
            }

            /**
             * Get password.
             *
             * @return string
             */
            public function getPassword()
            {
                return $this->password;
            }

            /**
             * Set password.
             *
             * @param string $password
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function setPassword($password)
            {
                $this->password = $password;
            }

            /**
             * Get state.
             *
             * @return int
             */
            public function getState()
            {
                return $this->state;
            }

            /**
             * Set state.
             *
             * @param int $state
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function setState($state)
            {
                $this->state = $state;
            }

            /**
             * Get role.
             *
             * @return array
             */
            public function getRoles()
            {
                return $this->roles->getValues();
            }

            /**
             * Add a role to the user.
             *
             * @param Role $role
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function addRole($role)
            {
                $this->roles[] = $role;
            }

            /**
             * Get store.
             *
             * @return array
             */
            public function getStores()
            {
                return $this->stores->getValues();
            }

            /**
             * Get store.
             *
             * @return array
             */
            public function getStore($id)
            {
                return $this->stores->getValues();
            }

            /**
             * Add a store to the user.
             *
             * @param Role $store
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function addStore($store)
            {
                $this->stores[] = $store;
            }
        }
```

Entity/Store.php

```
    <?php
  *emphasized text*
    namespace Application\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * An example entity that represents a store.
     *
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="store")
     *
     * @author Tom Oram <tom@scl.co.uk>
     */
    class Store
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="storeName", length=255, unique=true, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $storeName;

        /**
         * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Product" )
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_store",
         *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="store_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
         * )
         */
        protected $products;

        /**
         * Initialies the roles variable.
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * Get the id.
         *
         * @return int
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set the id.
         *
         * @param int $id
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function setId($id)
        {
            $this->id = (int)$id;
        }

        /**
         * Get the store id.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getStoreName()
        {
            return $this->storeName;
        }

        /**
         * Set the store id.
         *
         * @param string $storeName
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function setStoreName($storeName)
        {
            $this->storeName = (string) $storeName;
        }

        /**
         * Get product.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function getProducts()
        {
            return $this->products->getValues();
        }

        /**
         * Add a product to the user.
         *
         * @param Role $product
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function addProduct($products)
        {
            $this->products[] = $products;
        }

    }
```

Entity/Product.php

```
    <?php
    namespace Application\Entity;

    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * An example entity that represents a product.
     *
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="product")
     *
     * @author Tom Oram <tom@scl.co.uk>
     */
    class Product
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Store")
        */
        protected $stores;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
         */
        protected $title;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $sku;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=false)
         */
        protected $description;

        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Column(type="decimal",precision=12, scale=2, nullable=false)
         */
        protected $pricingIncl;

        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Column(type="decimal",precision=12, scale=2, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $cost;

        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
         */
        protected $taxgroup;

        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Column(type="decimal",precision=12, scale=2, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $sale;

        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=false, nullable=false)
         */
        protected $stock;

        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=false, nullable=false)
         */
        protected $stockstate;

        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=false, nullable=false)
         */
        protected $autostock;  

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Image", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
         * )
         */
        protected $images;

        /**
         * Initialies the roles variable.
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
            $this->stores = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * Get the id.
         *
         * @return int
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set the id.
         *
         * @param int $id
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function setId($id)
        {
            $this->id = (int)$id;
        }

        /**
         * Get store.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function getStores()
        {
            return $this->stores->getValues();
        }

        public function addStores(Collection $stores){
            foreach($stores as $store){
                $this->stores->add($store);
            }
        }

        public function removeStores(Collection $stores){
            foreach($stores as $store){
                $this->stores->removeElement($store);
            }
        }


        /**
         * Get the title.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTitle()
        {
            return $this->title;
        }

        /**
         * Set the title.
         *
         * @param string $title
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function setTitle($title)
        {
            $this->title = (string) $title;
        }

        /**
         * Get the sku.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getSku()
        {
            return $this->sku;
        }

        /**
         * Set the sku.
         *
         * @param string $sku
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function setSku($sku)
        {
            $this->sku = (string) $sku;
        }

        /**
         * Get the description.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getDescription()
        {
            return $this->description;
        }

        /**
         * Set the description.
         *
         * @param string $description
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function setDescription($description)
        {
            $this->description = (string) $description;
        }

        /**
         * Get the pricing incl tax.
         *
         * @return int
         */
        public function getPricingIncl()
        {
            return $this->pricingIncl;
        }

        /**
         * Set the pricing incl tax.
         *
         * @param int $pricingIncl
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function setPricingIncl($pricingIncl)
        {
            $this->pricingIncl = $pricingIncl;
        }

        /**
         * Get the cost
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getCost()
        {
            return $this->cost;
        }

        /**
         * Set the cost
         *
         * @param int $cost
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function setCost($cost)
        {
            $this->cost = $cost;
        }

        /**
         * Get the tax group.
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getTaxgroup()
        {
            return $this->taxgroup;
        }

        /**
         * Set the tax group.
         *
         * @param int $taxgroup
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function setTaxgroup($taxgroup)
        {
            $this->taxgroup = (int) $taxgroup;
        }

        /**
         * Get the sale
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getSale()
        {
            return $this->sale;
        }

        /**
         * Set the sale
         *
         * @param int $sale
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function setSale($sale)
        {
            $this->sale = (int) $sale;
        }

        /**
         * Get the stock.
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getStock()
        {
            return $this->stock;
        }

        /**
         * Set the stock.
         *
         * @param int $stock
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function setStock($stock)
        {
            $this->stock = (int) $stock;
        }

        /**
         * Get the stock state
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getStockState()
        {
            return $this->stockstate;
        }

        /**
         * Set the stock state
         *
         * @param int $stockstate
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function setStockState($stockstate)
        {
            $this->stockstate = (int) $stockstate;
        }

        /**
         * Get the auto stock.
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getAutoStock()
        {
            return $this->autostock;
        }

        /**
         * Set the auto stock.
         *
         * @param int $autostock
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function setAutoStock($autostock)
        {
            $this->autostock = (int) $autostock;
        }

        /**
         * Get images.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function getImages()
        {
            return $this->images;
        }

        /**
         * Add a image to the product.
         *
         * @param Images
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function addImages(Collection $images)
        {
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                $image->setProduct($this);
                $this->images->add($image);
            }
        }

        /**
         * @param Collection $images
         */
        public function removeImages(Collection $images)
        {
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                $image->setProduct(null);
                $this->images->removeElement($image);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, your second approach is the better one. You should use repositories, or even better, the **Service classes** (that are handling repositories internally) to access your Users, Stores etc. In that case, there will be two separate services for users and stores respectively. Then, you do the call:

```
$user = $userService->get($userId);
```

to get the User, and:

```
$store = $storeService->get($storeId);
```

to get the Store you want.

As for the access control you can simply implement something like `hasStore(User $user, Store $store)` method in either service and just call it when needed.

There is a big question, of course, whether or not to introduce the Service Layer in your application in the first place but generally it is considered as a good practice (in most cases) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, try

```
$userrepository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Thuiswinkelen\Entity\User');
$user      = $userrepository->findOneBy(array('id' => $this->getUserId()));
$stores = $user->getStores();

$product = array();
foreach ($stores as $store) {
    $product[] = $store->getProducts();
}
```

But, I think it's a bad idea:

> ```
>     /**
>      * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
>      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Product" )
>      * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_store",
>      *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
>      *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="store_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
>      * )
>      */
>     protected $products;
> ```

My mind - you need another table with constraints idStore <-> idProduct